# Removing a painted picture on my car

Tags: paint

I recently bought a 2003 Deville, someone had hand brush painted a small picture of Mickey Mouse leaning against the Cadillac symbol. It is very dry. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remove it without damaging my cars paint?

Comment: Do you have any photos? This is a hilarious question.

Comment: Yes, this question definitely deserves a photo to immortalize the artist's work. ;-)

Comment: I'll post a photo for Ya

Comment: tried sanding it with 6000grit sand paper? and then polishing it

Answer (score 3):

For Mickey?  Goof Off.  Seriously, probably your best chance.  Just use a little at a time.  Tell him Goofy is coming to take him away.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, it won't go away. Here is how you remove brush painted graphics, lettering, etc. I run a vehicle prep business and we get this all the time.  Use EZ Off Oven Cleaner, not the turquoise label, but the yellow label.

You spray it on, let it set a few minutes, 5 or less, and wipe with a soft cloth. Repeat. Each time, maybe a third of the paint will come off. It won't hurt factory paint. EZ Off removes One Shot Lettering Enamel, Rustoleum and every other brushable paint we have ever run across.

Comment: amazing tip !!!!